# FileSystemWatcher.Created is not working properly

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I want to monitor some directory using FileSystemWatcher but FileSystemWatcher.created is not working at all .

**CODE**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;



    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Xml;


    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
         class Program
         {
            static string fileName;
            static string dirFileName;

         static void Main(string[] args)
         {

              string _Dir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Dir"];



              Console.WriteLine("MAIDProcessFileTest processing started");
              FileSystemWatcher _watch = new FileSystemWatcher();
              _watch.Path = _Dir;
              _watch.Created += FileCreated;

              Console.ReadLine();
          }

          private static void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
          {

             Console.WriteLine("Before is treat");
             fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath);
             dirFileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath) + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath);

          }
      }
 }
```

Can anybody tell me that why this code is not working ... whenever I debug _watch.Created += FileCreated; is not working at all. where is the error can anybody tell me . Please Help

Answer (score 3):

You need to start it

```
_watch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

[FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.enableraisingevents?view=netframework-4.7.2)

You should probably start here though

[FileSystemWatcher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2)

It has a great example, and everything you need to know to use it

Comment: you are absolutely right .. many many thanks :) .. great example link .. thanks for helping @Saruman